# JSON deserialization with angular.fromJson()

Tags: json, angularjs

Despite from the AngularJS [documentation for angular.fromJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson) being spectacular, I still don't know how to use it to its fullest potential.  Originally I have just been directly assigning the JSON data response from an HTTP request to a `$scope` variable.  I've recently noticed that Angular has a built-in `fromJson()` function, which seems like something I'd want to use.  If I use it, is it safer and can I access data elements easier?

This is how I've been doing it:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.reddit.com/r/2007scape.json'
}).then(function success(response) {
    var mainPost = response; // assigning JSON data here
    return mainPost;
}, function error(response) {
    console.log("No response");
});
```

This is how I could be doing it:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.reddit.com/r/2007scape.json'
}).then(function success(response) {
    var json = angular.fromJson(response); // assigning JSON data here
    return json;
}, function error(response) {
    console.log("No response");
});
```

Comment: `response` should already be parsed to array or object ..not json string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pointless to convert the response to json as angular does it for you. From [angular documentation of $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> Angular provides the following default transformations:
>
> ***Request transformations*** (`$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest` and `$http.defaults.transformRequest`):
>
> If the data property of the request configuration object contains an object, serialize it into JSON format.
>
> ***Response transformations*** (`$httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse` and `$http.defaults.transformResponse`):
>
> If XSRF prefix is detected, strip it (see Security Considerations section below).
>   If JSON response is detected, deserialize it using a JSON parser.